# How do I use regex in `proxy_cookie_domain`

Tags: nginx

I'm using the [`proxy_cookie_domain`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#) directive, and the docs say I should be able to use regex:

> The directive can also be specified using regular expressions. In this
>   case, domain should start from the “~” symbol. A regular expression
>   can contain named and positional captures, and replacement can
>   reference them:
>
> ```
> proxy_cookie_domain ~\.(?P<sl_domain>[-0-9a-z]+\.[a-z]+)$ $sl_domain
> ```

How do I use regex to replace every instance of `example.com` with `mydomain.com`, e.g.:

- `anything.example.com` with `anything.mydomain.com`
- `any.thing.example.com` with `any.thing.mydomain.com`
- `literally.any.thing.example.com` with `literally.any.thing.mydomain.com`
- And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out nginx uses the PRCE flavor of regex, which you can play with at [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Here's my what I came up with

```
proxy_cookie_domain ~\.((?<cookie_pre>.*)example.com)$ "${cookie_pre}mydomain.com";
```